# The DRASTIC groundwater vulnerability model and it's relevance today

Tags: models, groundwater, pollution, hydrogeology

I am reading a groundwater pollution vulnerability study by Mark Angle of the Ohio Dpet. of Natural Resources (ODNR) for my county. The model used to assess the groundwater vulnerability for the county is called DRASTIC. The model was developed by the National Water Well Association for the EPA. I am simply curious as to whether or not the DRASTIC model is still a widely used tool in the world of hydrogeology?

Further, the study says that the model is designed to be accurate for map-able units of 100 acres or greater in size. Could DRASTIC be improved upon to model areas on a per 50 acre basis or less? Is there even any reason to?